# Set ImageSource to local filepath containing % characters

Tags: c#, wpf, uri, imagesource

I'm currently trying to set the ImageSource of the background of a button in C# / WPF. I'm doing this programatically, because I'm displaying a button for every (image) file in a certain choosable directory and therefore do not know the amount of buttons beforehand.

While iterating over every image file in the diectory I tried to instantiate a BitmapImage (for the current index) with:

```
private string[] _pathsInCurrentFolder;
public ImageSource[] ImagesInCurrentFolder { get; private set; }

//...

ImagesInCurrentFolder[i] = new BitmapImage(new Uri(_pathsInCurrentFolder[i]));
```

This works fine for most filepaths. However I came across some files containing % characters followed by (at least) two numbers. Interestingly this does not seem to be a problem in most cases, however one file had "%7E" as a substring. The URI Constructor converted it into "~" (As 7E is Ascii for ~) and the system threw a FileNotFoundException when trying to access the filepath.

So my question is: How do I instantiate an ImageSource object pointing to a local image file containing the substring "%7E" or possibly other breaking substrings I'm not yet aware of. I don't insist on a solution using URIs, anything that works is fine.

I'm running Win7 Prof 64bit, VS 2015 with .NET 4.6.1 btw.

I already tried (without success):

- Replacing "%" with `Uri.HexEscape("%")`, this broke all other filepaths with occurences of "%".
- Changing the `UriKind` in the `Uri` constructor. Whatever setting had no effect.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Uri.EscapeUriString`, startwith `file:///`, and change `\` to `/`:

```
string fileName="D:\\a%7E.jpg";
var bmp = new BitmapImage(
    new Uri(Uri.EscapeUriString(@"file:///" + fileName.Replace('\\', '/'))));
```